# How does one retrieve a random object from an NSSet instance?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I can grab a random value from an array-like structure by retrieving a random index.

How can I grab a random value from an NSSet object that stores NSNumber objects? I couldn't find an instance method of NSSet that retrieves a random value.

Comment: use `[mySet allObjects]` which will return an array and then use your existing logic for getting a random index

Comment: bbum caught a big mistake I made in my answer, thanks. Deleted.

Comment: Do you want random, or do you just not care which? Specifically, I mean, "Are you aware of `-[NSSet anyObject]`?"

Comment: Quoting anyObject docs: `The object returned is chosen at the set’s convenience—the selection is not guaranteed to be random.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, you can't directly retrieve a random object from an `NSSet`.

You either need to turn the set into an array -- into something that has an index that can be randomized -- by re-architecting your code to use an array or you could implement this using this bit of pseudo-code:

```
randomIndex = ...random-generator....(0 .. [set count]);
__block currentIndex = 0;
__block selectedObj = nil;
[set enumerateObjectsWithOptions:^(id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    if (randomIndex == currentIndex) { selectedObj = obj; *stop = YES }
    else currentIndex++;
 }];
 return selectedObj;
```

Yes -- it iterates the set, potentially the whole set, when grabbing the object.  However, that iteration is pretty much what'll happen in the conversion to an NSArray anyway.  As long as the set isn't that big and you aren't calling it *that* often, no big deal.

Comment: The general idea here is correct, however I needed to tweak it and implement the pseudo-code in order to compile. Here's my version: https://gist.github.com/4392708

Answer (score 4):

Whilst I like that @bbum answer will terminate early on some occasions due to the use of `stop` in the enumeration block.

For readability and ease of remembering what is going on when you revisit this code in the future I would go with his first suggestion of `turn the set into an array`

```
NSInteger randomIndex = ..random-generator....(0 .. [set count])
id obj = [set count] > 0 ? [[set allObjects] objectAtIndex:randomIndex] : nil;
```